# Algorithm - Find locations close/nearby to a given route

Tags: routes, path, location, dijkstra, direction

My problem is somewhat similar to Dijkstra's shortest paths algorithm but I am not sure if it's suitable for my case. So, I 'm going to explain this with an example.

Let's say we have a shipping company that delivers boxes (via road) to 10 destinations. I want to find the min amount of travels that serve the most destinations?
If a travel starts from location A and has a destination of B, maybe there is another location C on the same direction that can be served as well?

What I am thinking to do is find the destination (let's call it Z) that is further from the origin A and create a 'route' from A to Z. Then for all other locations get a radius and check if it intersects the calculated route.

I hope that makes sense. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you are not interested in minimizing travel time or distance, but minimizing the number of different paths to cover all destinations. Is that correct ?  The destination further from the origin (Z) may not give you maximal "coverage. For example, Z might be 200 km north and all others are closer to the origin, but south.

Comment: @c0der You are correct yes. Please correct me if I 'm wrong but after some searching I think I want an implementation of a 'Vehicle Routing Problem' algorithm.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help with it. [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/solving-minimum-path-cover-on-a-dag-21b16ca11ac0) might be relevant